# Finding the Distance Between Two Lines that represent GPS routes (MATLAB, Java, C++, or Python)

Tags: c++, python, matlab, gps, distance

I have been researching and trying to figure this one out to no avail. I have found many ways not to solve this...
The gist of the problem: I am looking for a method to calculate the deviance from an original path traveled by way of GPS coordinates. I have multiple csv files that contain latitude, longitude, and UTC time. I have created KML files from this information for a visual viewing of the deviance and now would like to put a value on this deviation. I ahve chosen a route as a reference and would like to measure the other routes against the reference route. There are multiple routes each having it's own reference route, each of which has many runs. No two runs are the same, and some of the routes deviate more than the next. I cannot use time, only lat and lon since the runs were completed over many weeks of data collection.

What I have tried thus far:
Haversine and Equirectangular formulas (looping through and measuring point to point). 
Outcome: The coordinates only line up for a short period of time and the difference in the number of points varies greatly.
Area under each curve: was going to find the difference of the two routes by this method.
Outcome: Really unsure how to proceed, nor find equations suitable for this calculation.

There were a couple more feeble attempts, but have been working on this for a few weeks now, with not much to show for and still unsure on how to proceed.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution 1**: Instead of calculating the "sideways" deviation between the two routes, just compare the respective arc lengths (Matlab: [arclength](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34871-arclength)).

**Possible solution 2**: To compare two routes, each going from the same start A to the same end point B: Draw a straight line between A and B, place a number of equidistant points along AB, and then average the perpendicular distance from these points on AB to the paths you want to compare. The absolute difference between the cumulative deviations from the straight-line reference is your deviation.

**Possible solution 3**: Calculate the arc length of each route. Place a number of equidistant points along each route. Average the distance between these points.

Both solution 2 and 3 will depend on the number of points you place, but with a higher number of points, the average deviation will converge. Note that these solutions are both related to calculating the area under each curve.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My next attempt was to sum each point-to-point distance using the Haversine Formula for each route, then measuring against the reference route for deviation. Would this be analogous to an arclength solution? It seems that it would however, I am not sure if this is mathematically sound.